# Ionic - App is going fullscreen on Android for no reason

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic hybrid mobile app.
After a recent build, I noticed that my app goes fullscreen (statusbar visible) after start for no reason. The first view is a Google Map and when it is loaded, the ionic.Platform.fullScreen(false, true); is called. It is because if the user opens the app for first time, there's a fullscreen intro shown, then the user is navigated to the map, which shouldn't be fullscreen. If this transition happens (the intro is opened) everything is fine, but if the user opens the app second+ time (no intro), then the map gets fullscreen with the statusbar visible, so half of the header is covered.

[image: statusbar is hidden]

This happens only on Android. I recently upgraded Cordova CLI version, cordova-andoid version (because of missing splashscreen bug) plus Linux version. Tried many from cordova: 6.0.0, 6.4.0, 6.5.0; cordova-android: 6.0.0, 6.2.1., 6.2.2, 6.2.3

First I thought it is related to where I build, but now it turns out that this isn't completely true.

Current setup:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.0.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 17.04 
Node Version: v4.4.0
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

UPDATE:
My config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.myapp" version="0.8.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>
        My desc.
    </description>
    <author email="developers@me.com" href="http://myapp.com/">
        MyApp Co.
  </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="CDVLocation" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~1.2.1" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="7000" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
    <preference name="xwalkVersion" value="19+" />
    <preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
    <preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded" />
    <preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="true" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <hook src="hooks/before_build/010_some_hook.js" type="before_build" />
    <hook src="hooks/after_prepare/020_other_hook.js" type="after_prepare" />
    <platform name="android">
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    </platform>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-fcm" spec="~2.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.7.0" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~6.2.1" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="~1.7.4">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="myid" />
        <variable name="APP_NAME" value="MyApp" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

List of plugins we use:

```
"cordovaPlugins": [
  "cordova-plugin-geolocation",
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
  "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview",
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
  "cordova-plugin-fcm",
  "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator",
  "cordova-plugin-x-toast",
  {
    "variables": {
      "FABRIC_API_KEY": "mykey",
      "FABRIC_API_SECRET": "mysecret"
    },
    "locator": "cordova-fabric-plugin@1.1.1",
    "id": "cordova-fabric-plugin@1.1.1"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-device",
  "cordova-plugin-network-information",
  "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser",
  {
    "variables": {
      "APP_ID": "myid",
      "APP_NAME": "myapp"
    },
    "locator": "cordova-plugin-facebook4",
    "id": "cordova-plugin-facebook4"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation"
]
```

Comment: Does it happen when you emulate the device or in real devices (or both)? This behaviour is present at `ionic serve`? There is any log  when debuging? Have you modified the scss? Does it happen when replicating this proyect from the scratch?

Comment: Can you list the plugins you have installed? or even better, can you share your config.xml?

Comment: @PabloAlbaladejo it does not happen in Ionic Serve (there's no statusbar there), I did not try emulator, logs say nothing interesting, I don't think it's scss related, because does not happen with all build, I don't know what you mean by replicating this project from scratch.

Comment: @jcesarmobile I updated my questions with te config.xml and list of plugins

Comment: There is not status bar at ionic serve, but this wrong behaviour could happen with the sreen frame. I suggest use emulators/other devices in order to discard issues related with one specific android device/version. Scss could have diferent results depending on the browser (for example developing at Firefox browser, deploying at Android, i.e. Chrome) From the scratch means trying to isolate the minimun code whats reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can you try to use this preference ` <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />` or calling `StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);` on device ready event?

Comment: @vargen_ i agree with jcesarmobile's comments. Had the same issue during my app development and resolved it using following preferences in config.xml "<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />"

Comment: @vargen_ Note that the second preference was very important to me as it dint work with just StatusBarOverlaysWebView preference

Comment: @Gandhi in the config.xml he provided he already have `<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />`, only `<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />` is missing

Comment: @jcesarmobile sorry cesar, i overlooked it. As usual, its a privilege interacting with you again.

Comment: @jcesarmobile - you had the right intuition. If you post your comment as an event, I will grant you the bounty. Great job. Thanks.

Comment: @jcesarmobile yeah, please post an answer so I can accept it, thanks a lot

Comment: Done, but the truth is that I'm shocked that it works. After commenting I've been doing some tests and looking into the `cordova-plugin-statusbar` code and the preference is not implemented for Android, only the javascript call.

Comment: @jcesarmobile - well, after a few more builds it does the same stuff again :( So maybe it is unrelated, but it was very consistently bad before adding this preference. Do you have any more ideas?

Comment: Did you try with the javascript code? `StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);`. This looks looks like a bug on statusbar plugin, but sadly I'm not able to reproduce it. You can also try to downgrade to version 2.2.2 or older of the statusbar plugin, as `overlaysWebView` was introduced on 2.2.3. Does it happens on all devices?

Comment: I did a quick check and we were calling `$cordovaStatusbar.overlaysWebView(true)` after deviceReady. I moved that into an `if iOS` block. This was not causing us any issues for months. Anyway, now I re-built the app a few times and it seems to work. If after a few more builds it's still good I'll accept your answer, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, as I said, `StatusBar.overlaysWebView` method was added for android on the 2.2.3 version of the plugin, which was released like one month ago. And whoever did it, didn't document it. Also you are not pinning a version for the plugin, so it will pick latest, that's why on other computers might work fine if when they created the app a previous version of the plugin was downloaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting this preference `<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />` on the config.xml, or using this code `StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);` after device ready event might fix your problem.